# Get path to pictures directory

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I try to save an Image (Bitmap/byte[]) with my Xamarin.Android app.
I used

```
    private string getPathToFile(string fileName)
    {
        File dir = new File(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures), "imgen");
        if (dir.Exists())
        {
            dir.Mkdirs();
        }

        File image = new File(dir, fileName);
        return image.Path;
    }
```

So the returned path looks something like this:

```
"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/imgen/new.png"
```

But this path does not exist on the emulator as I checked with the Android Device Monitor. 
I read that this folder is some kind of link to a mnt/shell/emulated/... folder, which actually exists on the emulator.
But how can I retrieve this real path in my Application?

Comment: what's wrong with this code? Isn't it writing your image in emulator properly? i used something like this to write image in my sdcard (real device), it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use this code for devices:

```
path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
  Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;

string myPath= Path.Combine(path, "file.name");
```

For emulators, it does not work.

Comment: This works. The Problem was that the folder "imgen" wasn't created.

Comment: `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES`

Answer (score 1):

Please use following code...

```
private void CreateDirectoryForPictures()
    {
        App._dir = new File(
            Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DirectoryPictures), "imgen");
        if (!App._dir.Exists())
        {
            App._dir.Mkdirs();
        }
    }
```

And this `CreateDirectoryForPictures()` function call. Then Created folder `imgen`.